# How to simulate a Large Structure at low frequency in CST Microwave Studio?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism, microwave, high-frequency

In CST Microwave Studio, I attempted to simulate a large (215x30cm) loop structure at 1kHz. However, CST gives a warning of 'too large' mesh size. The mesh size increases up to 6 Billion, however, if the same structure is simulated in Megahertz, the mesh size is in the range of a few hundred thousand and is simulateable.

What could be a possible way to simulate this? I also tried simulating it on the CST Low Frequency and Statics studio but there is no way to provide an excitation port for the loop.